Evidence for $\oplus P\subseteq\#P$ and barriers to proving it
Is there evidence that $\oplus P\subseteq\#P$ and evidence towards $\oplus P\not\subseteq\#P$ ? We know $\oplus P\subseteq FP^{\#P}$
What are some barriers to proving this inclusion $\oplus P\subseteq\#P$?

If $\mathsf{\oplus P} \subseteq \mathsf{# P}$, then $\mathsf{\oplus P} \subseteq \mathsf{UP}$, and then (by Valiant-Vazirani) $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{BPP}^{\mathsf{UP}}$, which is getting close to $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{UP}$. Now, we don't know bad consequences of the latter, but it seems unlikely...

@JoshuaGrochow 1. If we assume $#P\subseteq PHCF\subseteq\oplus P=FCH=FP^{#P}$ does it make $\oplus P\subseteq#P$ any more plausible (like do barriers get ameliorated)?


If $#P\subseteq\oplus P$, is there any consequence? I do not see anything other than counting hierarchy collapsing.


@JoshuaGrochow Since $UL=NL$ is believed, is it any more likely that $\oplus L\subseteq# L$ holds?

Note also $PL^{PL}=PL$. So there is no obstruction to $# L\subseteq\oplus L$ since counting hierarchy collapses anyway in Logspace related counting classes.

What is $\oplus P\subseteq#P$ supposed to mean? $\oplus P$ is a class of languages, whereas $#P$ is a class of functions.

I can write $F\oplus P$ but it is the same.

What is $F\oplus P$, and what is the same as what?

Function ParityP. Symbolically they just use $\oplus P$ for both function and language classes for parityP.

@EmilJeřábek Parity-P says Yes or No whereas F-Parity outputs 1 or 0

@Tay Really? That’s even more confusing than before. So what is the exact definition used here? Does $F{\oplus}P$ consist only of 0–1 characteristic functions of $\oplus P$ predicates, or does it contain all functions of polynomially bounded length whose bitgraph is computable in $\oplus P$? This needs to be clearly defined. I initially read the question here with the 0–1 interpretation in mind, and Josh’s comment is consistent with it, but then Turbo started making wild claims about $#P\subseteq\oplus P$ in another question, and this requires functions of arbitrary polynomial-length growth.

The most natural usage of the notation would be that as a function class, $\oplus\mathrm P$ stands for the class of characteristic functions of $\oplus\mathrm P$ predicates, whereas $\mathrm{F{\oplus}P}$ is the class of polynomially bounded functions with $\oplus\mathrm P$ bit-graph, which actually coincides with $\mathrm{FP^{\oplus P}}$. Thus $\oplus\mathrm P$ is the class of 0–1 valued functions in $\mathrm{F{\oplus}P}$. But this is clearly inconsistent with Turbo's usage.

Btw, I assumed that the "PHCF" above was a typo for something, but it turns out to come from an old paper by Wagner, where he uses "CPH" to denote CH, and "PHCF" to denote FCH.

@EmilJeřábek Thank you. I will remove my question and repost.
